# Remove suggestions and autocapitalisation from NSTextView

Tags: macos, nstextview

I have a NSTextView and I have an issue: when I type lowercased word in text view in start of line, system suggest me word with uppercased first symbol and changes my word when I break the line or add whitespace.

What it looks like:

[image]

My text view configuration:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806146/completely-disable-nstextview-spell-checking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145529/5654667 - this answer solved my problem.